# Multiple Joins in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, join, timeout

I'm trying to run a query from multiple tables and I'm having an issue with the query taking over 10 minutes to provide just 3 records. The query is as follows:

```
select TOP 100 pm_entity_type_name, year(event_date), 
      pm_event_type_name, pm_event_name, pm_entity_name, 
      pm_entity_code, event_priority, event_cost 

from pm_event_priority, pm_entity, pm_entity_type, pm_event_type, pm_event 

where pm_event.pm_event_id = pm_event_priority.pm_event_id 
   And pm_entity.pm_entity_id = pm_event_priority.pm_entity_id 
   And pm_entity_type.pm_entity_type_id = pm_entity.pm_entity_type_id  
   And pm_event_type.pm_event_type_id = pm_event_priority.pm_event_type_id  
   And ( pm_entity.pm_entity_type_id = '002LEITUU0005T8EX40001XFTEW000000OZX' OR
         pm_entity_type.parent_id= '002LEITUU0005T8EX40001XFTEW000000OZX' ) 
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

I wonder, is there any way I can modify this query to possibly make the query a little faster?

Comment: What indexes are on your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Query performance can tank when you have to join many large tables together, particularly when the join columns are not properly indexed.  In your case, I suspect your tables are quite large (many rows) and the `_id` columns are not indexed.

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio, you can click on "Display Estimated Execution Plan" to see how the query optimizer is interpreting your query.  If you see a bunch of Table Scans rather than Index Scans/Seeks, this means SQL Server has to read through each and every row in your tables; a performance nightmare!  Try putting some indexes on the `_id` columns of each table (perhaps a clustered index), and/or using Database Engine Tuning Advisor to automatically recommend the best index structure to apply to your tables to improve this query's performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the query plan.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan) on how to obtain it.

Once you have a query plan, see if you can tell from the list what is so slow.  Chances are there are table scans because of missing indexes.

What happens if you take out the `TOP 100` and do a `SELECT *` using the same criteria?  If you get a ridiculous amount of data back, there may be missing join criteria.